# jquery once .next has reached its last div of type, apply function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to cycle through a list of divs of the same class, so far i have managed to figure that out.

However, once i have scrolled down to the last of div type, i want to launch a function.

here is the code:

```
if ($('#what-section').hasClass('visible')) {
    $('.sub-section').filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.sub-section').addClass('active');
```

once i reach the last .sub-section i would like to execute the function nextMainSection();

EDIT: here is the whole code if that help better:

```
function nextSection(event) {
    //go to next section
    typeof event !== 'undefined' && event.preventDefault();

    var visibleSection = sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible'),
        middleScroll = (hijacking == 'off' && $(window).scrollTop() != visibleSection.offset().top) ? true : false;

    var animationParams = selectAnimation(animationType, middleScroll, 'next');
    unbindScroll(visibleSection.children('.cd-section'), animationParams[3]);







     if ($('#what-section').hasClass('visible')) {
            $('.sub-section').filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.sub-section').addClass('active');
$('.sub-section:last').addClass('active');



        } else if (!animating && !visibleSection.is(":last-of-type")) {
            nextSectionSub();
        }


        function nextSectionSub() {
            animating = true;
            visibleSection.removeClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[1], animationParams[3], animationParams[4])
                .end().next('.cd-section').addClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[0], animationParams[3], animationParams[4], function () {
                    animating = false;
                    if (hijacking == 'off') $(window).on('scroll', scrollAnimation);
                });

            actual = actual + 1;
        }

        resetScroll();
    }
```

and as per request here is the live code. when you reach the black area, under google dev you'll see the classes activate fine, just need to exit that on scroll down by activating the previous mentioned function: http://www.onethousandsheep.com/stackoverflow

Comment: `$('.sub-section:last').addClass('active');` or `$('.sub-section').last().addClass('active');`

Comment: Although that is useful to me as now the last sub-section div stays visible on scroll down, it is not what i need, I need to then activate a function as I scroll down, rather that cycle through sub-section divs. (ps the scroll down is already implemented and all this is wrapped in a function that is linked to scroll down.)

Comment: Please add complete HTML and JS code. Also add live demo if possible

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

jQuery:

```
 function prevSection(event) {
        //go to previous section
        typeof event !== 'undefined' && event.preventDefault();

        var visibleSection = sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible'),
            middleScroll = (hijacking == 'off' && $(window).scrollTop() != visibleSection.offset().top) ? true : false;
        visibleSection = middleScroll ? visibleSection.next('.cd-section') : visibleSection;

        var animationParams = selectAnimation(animationType, middleScroll, 'prev');
        unbindScroll(visibleSection.prev('.cd-section'), animationParams[3]);



        //-----(My Added) Previous SUB-SECTION-----//

        if ($('#what-section').hasClass('visible')) {
            $('.sub-section').filter('.opacity').removeClass('opacity').prev().addClass('opacity');
            $('.sub-section').filter('.visible').prev('.sub-section').removeClass('up').addClass('visible');
            $('.sub-section').filter('.visible').next('.sub-section').removeClass('visible');
            if ($('.triggerSection').hasClass('opacity')) {
                prevSectionSub();
                $('.triggerSection').removeClass('opacity visible');
                $('.sub-section:first').addClass('opacity visible');
            }
        } else if (!animating && !visibleSection.is(":first-child")) {
            prevSectionSub();
        }

        //-----END-----//



        function prevSectionSub() {
            animating = true;
            visibleSection.removeClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[2], animationParams[3], animationParams[4])
                .end().prev('.cd-section').addClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[0], animationParams[3], animationParams[4], function () {
                    animating = false;
                    if (hijacking == 'off') $(window).on('scroll', scrollAnimation);
                });

            actual = actual - 1;
        }

        resetScroll();
    }

    function nextSection(event) {
        //go to next section
        typeof event !== 'undefined' && event.preventDefault();

        var visibleSection = sectionsAvailable.filter('.visible'),
            middleScroll = (hijacking == 'off' && $(window).scrollTop() != visibleSection.offset().top) ? true : false;

        var animationParams = selectAnimation(animationType, middleScroll, 'next');
        unbindScroll(visibleSection.children('.cd-section'), animationParams[3]);



        //-----(My Added) Next SUB-SECTION-----//

        if ($('#what-section').hasClass('visible')) {
            $('.sub-section').filter('.opacity').removeClass('opacity').next().addClass('opacity visible');
            $('.sub-section').filter('.visible').prev('.sub-section').removeClass('visible').addClass('up');
            if ($('.triggerSection').hasClass('opacity visible')) {
                nextSectionSub();
                $('.triggerSection').removeClass('opacity visible');
                $('.sub-section:last').addClass('opacity visible');
            }
        } else if (!animating && !visibleSection.is(":last-of-type")) {
            nextSectionSub();
        }

        //-----END-----//


        function nextSectionSub() {
            animating = true;
            visibleSection.removeClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[1], animationParams[3], animationParams[4])
                .end().next('.cd-section').addClass('visible').children('div').velocity(animationParams[0], animationParams[3], animationParams[4], function () {
                    animating = false;
                    if (hijacking == 'off') $(window).on('scroll', scrollAnimation);
                });

            actual = actual + 1;
        }

        resetScroll();
    }
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="triggerSection"></div>
        <div class="sub-section opacity visible">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="header-text">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-section">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="header-text">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-section">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="header-text">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="triggerSection"></div>
```

It's not pretty, it's hacking and I'm clearly not a developer. Works with keyboard up and down arrow, mouse scroll is buggy as the JQ doesn't take the CSS transition delays in considerationand doesn't reset scroll after each sub section is activated (if someone want to chime in on that I'd be thankful :).

Here is the live demo: http://www.onethousandsheep.com/stackoverflow/